# build repeat-x header

Tags: html, css

I have some layout css questions. Their more like best practices and whats the most efficient way to build this. Let me start with a diagram of what I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

This header menu background will be liquid and the buttons inside it will be fixed. So really its made up of a left button independent of the gray style background. Then 3 or more buttons in the gray style background followed by some icons and a search filed, all within the gray background. My main issue is getting started with how to achieve the grey background expanding to the browsers width 100% and still having 2 rounded corners at each end.

Here is a pseudo html structure

```
<div id="menuHeader">
<ul>
    <li class=""><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">button1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">button2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">button3</a></li>
    <li class="tools">
      <div class="icon">icon1</div>
      <div class="icon">icon2</div>
      <div class="icon">icon3</div>
      <div class="search"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now the css issue where do I put my repeating background. If I put it on the menuHeader as a background image then its going to be one long repeating background graphic with no left and right corners. 
Would I need to setup a div for left right and center. Then have my gray buttons inside that and my blue home button outside that center div to the left of the left div. Or is there a way to do it where I can use the existing tags I have now and not have to deal with extra empty div markup.

I'm sorry if I'm not more clear but the main question I think is clear how can I get the background graphic to have rounded corners along with repeating background. Then be able to add my buttons in as background graphics.

Update: this is not going to be html5 unfortunately

Comment: Until css3 support becomes more widespread and allows for multiple backgrounds on single elements (or better yet, the rounded border support), you'll have to put in empty elements to contain the "left" and "right" edges with the rounded corners.

Comment: If you use some of the new features available with HTML5, specifically rounded corners and gradients, you can produce this nicely without having to worry about background images at all.  Users with older browsers won't see the nice design but you can make it degrade gracefully.  Is this an option for you?

Comment: Is there a possibility of using a rounded left bar for button 1, a rounded right bar for tools and a normal bar for button2 and 3? This would seem to do what you want but be a bit too obvious that I feel I must have missed something...

Comment: Chris do you mean keeping the blue button separate to the left then adding a container div for all the gray content. Then having the first button in the container have the left rounded corner part of it and then having the search box have the right rounded corner on it. Then the repeating background be on the container divs background. IS this what you are saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#menuHeader {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("bg.png") repeat;/*An image which has a width of 1px is sufficient*/
}
#leftSide, #rightSide{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;/*Whatever width*/
  height: 40px;/*Whatever height*/
}
#leftside{
  background: url("left.png") transparent;
}
#rightside{
  background: url("right.png") transparent;
}
```

Add this HTML inside the div#menuHeader:

```
<div id="menuHeader">
  <div id="leftside"></div><div id="rightside"></div><!--This location is chosen, so that the automatic z-indexing causes the background to stay at the background-->
  ....
</div>
```

Create two images (or one, to reduce server load, and use [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position)). If you want to add that blue box, expand the left background-image. Make sure that the elements inside the div#menuHeader have a transparent or no background.

Comment: Thanks Rob, so where would the center repeating background go thats going to adjust to 100% of the browser.

Comment: So where is the center background image I presume its on menuHeader background? Also does <div id="leftside"></div><div id="rightside"></div>  just go at the bottom of the ul tag I have or does this need to be altered.

Comment: The background should be added to `div#menuheader`. A width of 1px is enough, because the image is going to be repeated until the whole element is filled. Place the `<div id="leftside">...</div>` right after the `<div id="menhuHeader">`, so that the background-border-divs stays at the background. If you have a (moral) objection to place these elements right after the `div#menuHeader`, add an aditional style to these: `z-index:-1`.

Comment: Ok excuse my stupidity but where does my ul structure go. between the left and right divs or before it? Also what does this mean <!--This location is chosen, so that the automatic z-indexing causes the background to stay at the background-->

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see your comments until I had posted. I'll give this a try and get back if I have any questions that's for the help.

Comment: I presume I need to put a position  the rightside div in css to be to the right of the page. Could I use float:right

Comment: I do not recommend applying `float:right` at `<div id="leftside">`. When the elements (menu) has a too large width, the floated element will cause the menu to move down.